# Windows 11 Taskbar disappears when switching between 1 monitor and 2 monitors, and switching primary monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11, taskbar

I use both 1 and 2 monitors often, and I switch between the setups frequently. In this post, the larger 1440p monitor will be referred to as the `LG`, and the smaller 1080p one `HP`.

**The Windows taskbar disappears when switching from "Extended" using both monitors, to "PC Screen Only" on the LG.** It doesn't reappear by itself, and I have to go into the `Personalization > Taskbar` settings and toggle "Show badges over taskbar apps", restart Windows Explorer, or press CTRL-ALT-DEL to get it back. The taskbar doesn't return otherwise, even when extending/unextending the monitors.

### Additional Information

- Windows 11 Home 22H2 22621.1992
- Nvidia RTX 3070Ti, GeForce Game Ready Driver 531.79
- The monitors are connected to the PC via DP cables into the GPU

#### Taskbar settings

[image: taskbar settings]

#### Single monitor settings

[image: single monitor]

#### Dual monitor settings

[image: dual monitor]

#### Advanced Display settings

[image: lg]
[image: hp]

#### Taskbar on single monitor

[image: 1 monitor taskbar]

#### Taskbar on extended

[image: extended taskbar]

#### Missing taskbar when switching back to "PC Screen Only"

[image: pc screen only taskbar]

Comment: Does the taskbar disappear from both monitors ?

Comment: @harrymc It disappears on both monitors. In the screenshots, I've set the task bar to my main display only (the larger one).

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the layout of  the monitors in *Settings > System > Display* with one and two monitors, indicating well which one is what. Question: What is your display card and which driver are you using for it? How are the monitors connected? Does the taskbar appear if you move the cursor over its place?

Comment: @harrymc more information added.

Comment: Does the taskbar appear if you move the cursor over its place or move it to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @harrymc It does not, because I don't have the "Automatically hide the taskbar" option turned on. It should show at all times.

Comment: I let my taskbar only show on my primary monitor, and I never have this issue, over 5-6 different setups which I regularly switch. Try to make the WHOLE taskbar visible on the secondary monitor (remove the "where window is open" part)

Answer (score 2):

There have been many reports of this problem in successive
Windows versions, but few solutions/workarounds.

Below is a list of some workarounds that worked for some persons.

- Disabling the Search box in the taskbar.
  This is done in *Settings > Personalization > Taskbar*.
- Restarting Explorer.
  This is done in Task Manager - select `explorer.exe` and click
  "Restart task".
- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
  and going back by <kbd>Esc</kbd> refreshes the taskbars.
- The post
  [Windows 11 Taskbar DISAPPEAR on switch between Multiple Monitors and/or Monitor Modes (PC Screen Only, Duplicate, Extend, etc.)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-taskbar-disappear-on-switch-between/d8b8dba3-2a78-4773-b9d4-e8cefb7c85b2)
  says:

> It seems Windows Tools like "displayswitch.exe" does not properly "refresh" the Taskbar on switching Display Modes!
> I've written a small Application by myself which can toggle Display Modes from Single to Extended and then send a WM_SETTINGCHANGE Broadcast Message to workaround this Bug!

The poster above added the C programming command-line that
he used:

```
SendMessageTimeout((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, "TraySettings", SMTO_NORMAL | SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, out lpdwResult);
```

I have tried to duplicate it using
the free [AutoHotkey V1](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will issue the HWND_BROADCAST
Windows message when <kbd>F9</kbd> is pressed:

```
F9::SendMessage, 0x1A,0,"TraySettings",, ahk_id 0xFFFF  ; 0x1A is WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0xFFFF is HWND_BROADCAST
```

Using this script :
After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: 1. My toolbar searchbox is completely disabled.
2. I've also found pressing ctrl-alt-delete and going back refreshes the taskbar.
3. Not sure if I'm comfortable installing AHK and copy-pasting an unknown script into my startup folder.

Comment: AHK is your choice to install or not, for me this is an important tool. I added your workaround to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to replicate this issue on my system.

It makes me think that it could be graphics driver related. I would try the following steps, any single one could resolve the issue:

- Physically swap the DP or HDMI ports your monitors are connected to. If your GPU has more than two ports, try all combinations.
- Uninstall all Nvidia software. Make a test before reinstalling graphics driver. Then, [clean install](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/geforce-graphics-cards/5/139267/clean-installation-of-nvidia-graphics-drivers/) your graphics driver. Only after a test, install further Nvidia software, if needed.
- Make a Windows [startup repair](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/use-startup-repair-in-windows-11.14660/)
- If you had made an in-place upgrade from Windows 10, consider doing a clean install of Windows 11

**Possible Workaround** :
Should you not find a solution, take into consideration to change your habits, and show the full taskbar on all screens.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, it's broken (again?) like it was in Windows 10 a while ago and it is a Windows Bug that is "known" but no one cares!

Since MS does **NOT** fix any of their Bugs for Years now but instead added new **broken** "Features"...
So I started to try 3rd Party tools that maybe can fix it.

And the Answer is: Start11

Sadly it is not a portable App and could be more advanced, but it fixes the Problem for now!

Comment: What does Start11 do that fixes this? What is Start11?